Dimensions of coaxial feed in HFSS
I am designing an antenna that will be fed coaxially. I have determined the position I want to attach.
I have modeled a simple coaxial probe in HFSS, with an inner conducting pin, vacuum, and outer conductor that's grounded. Then, I have a via that connects the patch to the pin of the coaxial cable.
The radius of the via and the radius of the coaxial pin must be the same in this case to have minimal reflections. In the practical setup, I will be using an SMA connector at the bottom plate (it will not have its own pin directly to patch but will be connected with a via.)
Does the radius of the pin in the coaxial probe I use in HFSS have any importance, as long as the probe stays at 50 ohms?
How do I determine the correct via radius (patch to pin of coaxial) for the real setup?

Can you add a picture of the HFSS model?  This is a little hard to picture just from your description.

The gap to ground plane controls Zo then LC of via affects SRF


The radius of the via and the radius of the coaxial pin must be the same in this case to have minimal reflections.

In that case you will almost certainly want to fill your coaxial feed with something other than vacuum, to allow you to match the characteristic impedance of the feed with (depending on what you want to measure) the characteristic of the via and its return path, the impedance of the antenna, or the system impedance of the system where the antenna will be used.
If you want to minimize reflections in general, you'll probably just optimize the feed dimensions to minimize reflections.
If you want to minimize reflections specifically at the interface between the feed and the via, you'll match the feed impedance to the via-and-return-path impedance (I'd make a 2nd test model in HFSS with just a via and no antenna to optimize this before transferring the dimensions to your primary design).
If you want to know how the whole design (antenna and via) will perform in a system, then you should not minimize reflections at all. Just match the feed impedance to the system impedance using the well-known formula for characteristic impedance of a coaxial line. You do have the freedom to trade off inner conductor diameter vs dielectric constant to match the inner conductor diameter to the via diameter but getting this slightly off will not likely produce significant spurious reflections, unless you are working at a frequency that is too high for your design anyway.
